# Order by MYSQL with two params

Tags: mysql

I have a problem and i don't know how fix it!...

I have a table "products", it has 2 columns "great" (bool: 0 - 1) and "order" (num: 0 - n)... I need order all records with the follow rules:

```
1.- First, all with "great" in 1 and all with "order" > 0.
2.- All with "great" and "order" = 0
3.- All with "great" = 0 and "order" > 0.
4.- All with "great" = 0 and "order" = 0.
```

I need it in one sql, so i don't know if it possible. I tried with:

`ORDER BY great DESC, order DESC`
... so first order great with 1 and after order with numbers.. but sometimes order with 4 and great with 0, it almost at first of statement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can `ORDER BY` with expressions, like so:

```
ORDER BY `great` DESC, `order` > 0 DESC
```

*(note that it is DESC because "true" is greater than "false")*

Also, if you want the `order > 0` records sorted in ascending order, you can do this:

```
ORDER BY `great` DESC, `order` > 0 DESC, `order` ASC
```